# How to mock autofac type registration?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofac

I have following registration in my autofac container:

```
builder.RegisterType<EmailService>().As<IEmailService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<AzureBlobStorageService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Some commands depend on these services. But in my tests I don't need them, it's not what I want to test.

So I tried to rewrite registrations in following way:

```
builder.RegisterType<Mock<EmailService>>().As<IEmailService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<Mock<AzureBlobStorageService>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

But I'm getting error:
Message: System.ArgumentException : The type 'Moq.Mock 1[EmailService]' is not assignable to service 'Moq.Mock`1[[IEmailService, ...]]'.

How to do it proper way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to register a mock for the `IEmailService` interface, you could use the `RegisterInstance` method:

```
builder.RegisterInstance(new Mock<IEmailService>().Object)
    .As<IEmailService>();
```

Comment: @user1178399: Did you try this?